# iOS App ECSlidingViewController: add new viewcontroller and transient to it

Tags: ios, ecslidingviewcontroller

I use ECSlidingViewController in my App. There're four ViewControllers come with the sample code. These four ViewControllers corresponds to four option in the "MenuViewContoller".

Now I want to add a TableViewController in the "FirstTopViewController". Each cell of this TableViewController leads to a ViewController which is not one of the four predefined ViewControllers.

I saw that ECSlidingViewController ships a 'SampleTableViewController". But I don't know how to 'transient' to this ViewController.

I did work with UINavigationController before. I know how to push a view controller to NavigationController. I don't know how to cooperate UINavigationController with ECSlidingViewController.

Thanks a lot.

Here is a demonstration:
http://www.penghou.net/file/question.png

Answer (score 0):

ECSlidingViewController is a container, just like UINavigationController. You give it view controllers and it displays and transitions between them.

`ECSlidingViewController` provides methods for setting view controllers and transitioning between them by calling anchor/reset. Check the header file for documentation on these methods.